# XQuery - Using sum() returns NaN for string values

Tags: string, sum, xquery, nan

Trying to sum the total earnings from the top NBA players in 2012-2013 from this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highest-paid_NBA_players_by_season

Here is my code:

```
sum(
let $doc := doc("NBApaid.xml")//table
for $x in $doc
where $x/tr/td/h2/span/@id ="2012.E2.80.932013"
for $y in $x/tr/td
where $y/h2/span = "2012–2013"
for $z in $y//td
where starts-with($z,"$")
let $a := substring($z, 2,10)
return number($a)
)
```

And the output is:

```
NaN
```

The problem here is that the`number($a)` returns a whole column of NaNs.

When I only return $a before converting it using number(), the output looks like this:

```
30,453,805
20,907,128
19,948,799
19,752,645
19,444,503
19,285,850
19,067,500
19,067,500
18,673,000
18,668,431
```

How come I can't convert the strings?

Answer (score 1):

Use `number(translate(xxx, ',', ''))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your output strings are not real numbers, because the thousand separator `,` is not part of an XQuery number. So you will have to remove the separator from the string. For this, you can either use `translate()` as @MichaelKay rightfully suggests.

You could also use `replace()`, the difference between the two functions being that `translate()` only replaces single characters (which is all you need in this case) and replace can use regex. However, I personally feel that replace is a much more logical name and easier to read, so I personally tend to not use `translate()`.

Also, if your processor supports XQuery 3.1 you can use the arrow notation and write it like this:

```
let $a := substring($z, 2, 10) => replace(",", "")
```